# How to use awk for joining two csv using a key column and write a another csv

Tags: awk, csv, join

I have two CSV with following data,

**file1.csv:-**

```
path(S1),filename,timestamp(S1),memory(S1)  
xx/APS50CC2,APS50CC2,23-09-2019,45  
yy/APS50CC3,APS50CC3,18-09-2019,25
```

**file2.csv :-**

```
path(S2),filename,timestamp(S2),memory(S2)
mm/APS03CR1,APS03CR1,23-09-2019,200
zz/APS50CC2,APS50CC2,18-09-2019,55
```

**Expected output

output.csv :-**

```
filename,path(S1),timestamp(S1),memory(S1),path(S2),timestamp(S2),memory(S2)
APS50CC2,xx/APS50CC2,23-09-2019,45,zz/APS50CC2,18-09-2019,55
APS50CC3,yy/APS50CC3,18-09-2019,25,Not found,Not found,Not found
APS03CR1,Not found,Not found,Not found,mm/APS03CR1,23-09-2019,200
```

I have tried `join` command and have run,it is working fine for smaller set of input. But when I run for about 500000+ records, it is giving errors, hence I do not want to use `join`, I want to try it out using `awk`...

I am kind of new to `awk`, kindly help me out with the syntax. 
The key here for joining is column 2 i.e. `filename`.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what error (exactly) you got with `join`, as that tool would be the most efficient to use here. Does you CSV files use tabs as field delimiter?

Comment: Actually there were duplicate rows for same key column ..Ex .  if a 'filename' is present in both csv,the o/p csv should actually have a single record for that 'filename' .But there were two entries, one with 'Not found' (used -e in join) in S1 columns and another with 'Not found' in S2 columns..

Comment: If you have a duplicated key in one file, that will generate multiple rows in the result. If the keys are unique, then there will only be a single line for each key in the output. If you still get multiple rows for a key in the output, then that key is _not_ unique (there might be a space character that makes them different). Is your data tab-delimited?

Comment: My data is comma delimited,I have checked manually ,the keys are unique in input files

Comment: Does that data now cause you issues with `join`? Because if it doesn't, I really see no issues with using `join`.

Comment: @ChethanSG, have you consider to use database? What you want is what databases are for.

Comment: It always did.Hence wanted to try out with 'awk' ..The original data has many columns.Sry i cant post the data..Here is the command i was using              
**join -i --nocheck-order -1 2 -2 2 -t, -a1 -a2 -o 0,1.1,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,2.1,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8 -e 'Not found' <(file1.csv) <(file2.csv) > output.csv**

Comment: @RomeoNinov Its just a tool

Comment: @ChethanSG, yes, it is. But wise man use the right tool for the job. :) .

Comment: as well as being unique, does each key occur once in each file? In this case you could `sort` them by this key and then combine them with `paste`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and running

```
mlr --csv join --ul --ur -j filename -f file1.csv \
then unsparsify --fill-with "Not found" \
then reorder -f "filename","path(S1)","timestamp(S1)","memory(S1)","path(S2)","timestamp(S2)","memory(S2)" file2.csv
```

you will have

```
+----------+-------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
| filename | path(S1)    | timestamp(S1) | path(S2)    | timestamp(S2) | memory(S2) | memory(S1)   |
+----------+-------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
| APS03CR1 | Not found   | Not found     | mm/APS03CR1 | 23-09-2019    | 200        | Not found    |
| APS50CC2 | xx/APS50CC2 | 23-09-2019    | zz/APS50CC2 | 18-09-2019    | 55         | 45           |
| APS50CC3 | yy/APS50CC3 | 18-09-2019    | Not found   | Not found     | Not found  | 25           |
+----------+-------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
```

I know it's not awk but Miller is another great tool for structured text